# Create a DB export using a function app and saving it to a secured storage account in Azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-function-app, azure-storage-account

I have a function app that is setup to run on a storage account that is open to all networks. I then created a function that utilizes the `New-AzSqlDatabaseExport` cmdlet to export a DB to a different storage account. I want the second storage account to be closed off to all networks for security reasons. When I try doing this I get the error:

```
[Error] ERROR: 0: There was an error that occurred during this operation : '<string xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/">Error encountered during the service operation. ; Exception Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Dac.Services.ServiceException:Unexpected exception encountered while retrieving metadata for blob &amp;#39;https://testingimmutableblob.blob.core.windows.net/testexportdb/bqm2018r3devexxonmobil_copy_2020-08-21.bacpac&amp;#39;.; Inner exception Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.StorageException:The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.; Inner exception System.Net.WebException:The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.;
```

I then went in and added a vnet to my function app and added the same vnet to the Firewall rules on the storage account. Again, when trying to export a copy of the DB I get the same error. Does anyone have any ideas?